# How can I write a "idempotent" .Xmodmap

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xmodmap

Currently I have an `.Xmodmap` file that changes my <kbd>Command</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then changes my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd> (I'm running Linux on a Mac).

It works quite well, when only run once but on successive runs (for example when I restart my desktop environment (Cinnamon) it reloads the `.Xmodmap` file) it basically resets the settings by reverting the changes. Effectively toggling between my desired setup and the original setup.

How can I write an `.Xmodmap` file that only sets the settings one time, but doesn't change them back on successive runs? Here is my existing `.Xmodmap` file:

```
clear control
clear mod4

keycode 105 =
keycode 206 =

keycode 133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 134 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L

add control = Control_L
add control = Control_R
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. I have no idea what “modal” means here. This `.Xmodmap` only affects the keys that you're changing, what do you want to do differently?

Comment: When I use the .Xmodmap it sets the keys, if I run it again it switches them back. I want create a .Xmodmap that no matter what results in the swapped control and command keys.  Sometimes when restart the DE .Xmodmap is run again resulting in an annoyance.

Comment: @coteyr I think the word you're looking for is "[idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reset the map to its original state before applying your mods. A full reset takes forever, so best I can come up with is diffing.

This code uses `.Xmodmap{.orig,.reset,.mods}` where if `.orig` doesn't exist it's set to the current state, and calculates `.reset` to restore that state from wherever it's got to. before applying `.mods`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# file xmodmap-reset

#     rm ~/.Xmodmap.orig
# beforehand to take current setup as baseline for Xmodmap.mods changes

stem=~/.Xmodmap
orig=${stem}.orig
reset=${stem}.reset
mods=${stem}.mods

# implement -pme like -pke
#
xmodmap-pme () {
  xmodmap -pm \
  | sed '
        1d
        / [^ ]/!d
        s/^[^ ][^ ]*/clear &\nadd & =/
        s/([^ ]*//g
    '
}

# save baseline if none atm
test -a $orig || {
    xmodmap  -pke
    xmodmap-pme
} > $orig

# payload, diff for commands to reset to baseline from current
{
    xmodmap  -pke
    xmodmap-pme
} \
| {
    diff -u0 $orig - \
    | sed -n '
        1,/^@@/d
        s/^[^+]clear/clear/p
        s/^-//p
      '
} > $reset
xmodmap $reset

# finally ready to apply the mods
test -a $mods && xmodmap $mods
```

(edit: cleanup)

Comment: I am giving this a try. So far so good.

Comment: @coteyr - is this working out for you?

Comment: Not really I am still experimenting.

Comment: Upadate: this seems to be working, for the most part I still have to tweak things a bit but at least the settings are not be reset on successive runs.

Comment: @coteyr - if this doesn't pan out I think I have another method which might work, but it's more involved, so I don't really want to write it up if this does the job. When replying please include the @ sign infront of my username so I know you replied, otherwise I have to come back and check and will most probably forget.

Comment: Yah, I was a bit elliptical there.  One last fix, the full reload is pretty slow

Comment: Okay, my apologies, that was a bit past 'exercise for the reader' territory.  @slm - if yours is any simpler, please do answer with it.

Comment: @jthill - the idea I had is definitely not simpler. The general idea would be to touch afile when the .xmodmap is loaded. This file would only be removed during a reboot, by the `rc.local`. It was a rough idea but should work. Wasn't sure about how robust it would be though. The file would amount to a "state" file that would guard the xmodmap from being reapplied once it had already been.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Will award bounty if there is not a better answer in a few days.

Comment: @slm I've been tempted to use the root window's name for per-server-incarnation stuff, I'm guessing no distributed package would dare hijack that.

Comment: @jthill - I would be surprised too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system > Preferences > Startup Applications and add `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.
[image: add xmodmap command]

Comment: This causes xmodmap to run every time the DE is restarted, this already works, and causes the settings to be set, then set back. For example Start computer, log in, DE is launched, xmodmap is run, DE crashes, DE starts, xmodmap is run. Now my keyboard is messed up again.

Comment: What about Xev? http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/xev-determine_custom_keybindings

Answer (score 0):

I'm still confused a little bit as to what you want, but I think this it:

If you put this in your `~/.Xmodmap`,

```
clear control
clear mod4

keysym Super_L = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Super_L

add control = Control_L
add control = Control_R
add mod4 = Super_L
add mod4 = Super_R
```

then every time `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` is executed, then the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left <kbd>⌘</kbd> key swap. So, on the first invocation, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key acts as though you pressed <kbd>⌘</kbd>, but on the second invocation, it resumes acting as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key again.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want

Comment: I want the exact opposite, I want every invocation, no matter what to result in command acting like control and control acting like command.

Comment: Okay, well, this is why I'm confused, because your original posting appears to do exactly what you want...

Comment: But it doesn't.

Comment: Well, the behavior I observe is that your code *is* idempotent, whereas my code is stateful. Are you telling me that both your code and mine behave identically for you? If that's the case, then I think you must be experiencing a bug of some sort.

I have a suggestion: try explicitly running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` from an xterm, and see if your code really does swap the keys with repeated application. Maybe your keys reverting to original behavior when Cinnamon restarts isn't for the reason you think it is?